# How to call another function with n-parameters in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've a function manipulating a given query string. And another version of it, which always uses `window.location.search`. This is the declaration:

```
class MyClass {
  public changeQuery(query: string; exclude: boolean = true; ...values: string[]): string {
    // a lot of stuff is going on here
  }

  public getQuery(exclude: boolean = true; ...values: string[]): string {
    let args: any[] = [...values];

    args.unshift(exclude);
    args.unshift(window.location.search);

    return this.changeQuery.apply(this, args); // <-- Error here @args
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, (boolean | undefined)?, ...string[]]'.
> Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '[string, (boolean | undefined)?, ...string[]]'.

So I think `let args` must have another type. But how can this be defined? The other option whould be to make `query: string` in the function `updateQuery` optional (and fill it inside the function with `window.location.search`, if undefined is given). Is this possible, too? This would be even better I think.

Comment: `this.changeQuery(window.location.search, exclude, ...values)`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad works like a charm. I created an answer to give other users a clearer view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems so, that Aluan Haddad gave the right answer, without creating an answer. I thought in javascript, so I was overthinking this.

```
public getQuery(exclude: boolean = true; ...values: string[]): string {
  return this.changeQuery(window.location.search, exclude, ...values);
}
```

Is working like a charm. That produces this javascript output:

```
getQuery(exclude = true, ...values) {
    let args = [...values];
    args.unshift(exclude);
    args.unshift(window.location.search);
    return this.changeQuery.apply(this, args);
}
```

That seems to be the code, I tried to produce in typescript.